# Can you call a coach's challenge when you do not have a timeout?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, video-review

In close game situations in the NFL, if for example the opposing quarterback completes a pass to one of their receivers, can you challenge the ruling on the field with no timeout? This is questionable, as you can call a timeout and then the officials will review that play. Also, you lose a timeout when you call a challenge, so why wouldn't coaches always challenge outside the 2 minute mark if you did not have a timeout to lose (assuming that the challenging team has a coach's challenge left)

Comment: You should be more specific about what level of football you are talking about as college and the pro have different rules.

Comment: I was meaning the NFL level, the pros, but thank you for that suggestion

Comment: The tags on this are still for both levels (collegiate is for college level sports) and amercian-football is for all levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A challenge with no timeouts left is not possible. And it will cost the team 15 yards, if the coach tries to do so.

[Section 2 - Instant Replay](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2018-nfl-rulebook/)

> A team may not challenge a reviewable play:
>
> - after the two-minute warning of each half;
> - throughout any overtime period;
> - after committing a foul that delays the next snap; and
> - **after exhausting all of its challenges or timeouts**.

Trying to challenge a call without permission is penalized as follows:

> If a team initiates a challenge when it is not permitted to do so, it
>   will be charged a timeout.
>
> For initiating a challenge when a team has exhausted its timeouts:
>   Loss of 15 yards.